# Beta-Binomial Derivation

Tags: bayesian, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

I was looking on wikipedia and seemed to be not follow how the beta-binomial is derived. I was hoping I could provide an example I found in a paper and someone could explain the steps.

Given the marginal

$$m(y)=\int_{0}^{1}6{n\choose{y}}p^{y+1}(1-p)^{n-y+1}dp$$

How do I get to here

$$=6{n\choose{y}}\frac{\Gamma(y+2)\Gamma(n-y+2)}{\Gamma(n+4)}$$

Comment: are you familiar with the beta function and its relationship with the gamma function?

Comment: That is what I am confused about. Any information or link would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If you click the link (in wikipedia) on the gamma and/or beta function there is explanation there of how they are related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are just two things you need to know for this.

First one: definition of the Beta function.

$$
B(x,y) := \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,\text dt.
$$

Second thing: the identity that
$$
B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
$$
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function) for a proof).
So you're basically there already, we just tidy up by hiding the integral in some nice special functions.

Comment: This derivation is nicer imo: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3540/774